# Linux powerpc syscall numbers: what are spu and nospu ABI and are 32 or 64 bit

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, powerpc

Looking into linux kernel powerpc syscall numbers in [arch/powerpc/kernel/syscalls/syscall.tbl](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/powerpc/kernel/syscalls/syscall.tbl), there are 5 ABI:

```
The <abi> can be common, spu, nospu, 64, or 32 for this file.
```

`common`, `32` and `64` are obvious, but what are `spu` and `nospu`. Are these 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to care about the SPUs. SPUs are the co-processors on the CELL powerpc processors. Pretty much dead now.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_(microprocessor)#Synergistic_Processing_Elements_(SPE)

Comment: I'm creating 2 files: 32bit syscalls and 64bit syscalls. Should I include `spu` and `nospu`?

Comment: If you just build the kernel tree for powerpc you'll get these build for you in ./arch/powerpc/include/generated/asm/syscall_table_32.h and ./arch/powerpc/include/generated/asm/syscall_table_64.h. To build these, 32bit uses "common,nospu,32" and 64bit uses "common,nospu,64"